# Can 3rd party javascript libraries be used with CartoDB?

Tags: carto, jquery

I'd like to build some functionality (search, sliders, etc.) in a 3rd party javascript library (jquery mobile), and integrate it with CartoDB.

Can this be done?  Are there any examples available or a cookbook decribing how to do the integration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible, but only if you roll your own application using the [SQL API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html), [Cartodb.js library](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js.html).

Also, Cartodb use jQuery under the hood already, as well as Backbone, underscore.js and a few others. In this [tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view.html) they demo using jQuery in a small cartodb app.

Unless you switch it to google maps, Cartodb uses Leaflet underneath as the map rendering library, and Leaflet has [many plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) that add additional features.

Once you're in your browser app, Cartodb.js is essentially a thin wrapper over Leaflet, so most tutorials or documentation relating to Leaflet will apply to Cartodb.js as well.

Here are a few things to read that I found searching for Leaflet + Jquery Mobile, they would be good starting points:

- [jQuery Mobile and Leaflet integration](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-leaflet-integration/)
- [jQuery mobile plugin for Leaflet](https://github.com/sebastian-meier/jquery.mobile.leaflet)

Comment: Casey-Very helpful, thank you much!  Are extending Leaflet with plugins and/or using JQuery mobile straightforward (for an experienced javascript developer), or is this something for which CartoDB would have to provide instructions and/or access?

Comment: It's easy. For example, I'm using the Leaflet Pan Control plugin in my little project see index.html and map.js https://github.com/Ramblurr/travel-map (Also please mark the question as answered if you feel it has been :D)